# PyQtDeploy "Unable to copy file"

Tags: python, deployment, pyqt5, pyqtdeploy

First time I build an application for Windows, so I used Python+pyqt5 since I had good experience with C++/Qt5 on Linux.

I'm now trying to get an executable for deployment, but the one generated py2exe complained about missing the Qt Windows plugin. I moved to pyqtdeploy as it seemed to be more specifically designed with pyqt in mind, but after setting the paths I just get an "Unable to copy file error".

Anybody got an idea how to get this to work?

The locations I set are as follows:

Interpreter: C:\Python34\python.exe

Include Directory: C:\Python34\include

Python Library: C:\Python34\DLLs\python3.dll

Standard Library Directory: C:\Python34\Lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, I faced the same problem. After some debugging I found out that pyqtdeploy looks for the correct `bootstrap-<version>.py` script it wants to use, by looking at the version in the filename of the Python library (`python3.dll` in our case).

The solution is to use `<windows-dir>\system32\python34.dll` or `<python-install-dir>\python34.dll` as the Python library. The former will be present when you install Python for all users, the latter will be present when you install Python "just for me" (see this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNXzI.png)).

<s>After renaming `python3.dll` to `python34.dll`, everything worked again.</s>

Comment: That seemed to work, but after talking to some Windows Developer they made me look for *.lib file, and lo and behold Python comes with python34.lib which just works(tm) for pyqtdeploy.